# How to transfer very large folders from a server which I access sudo and ssh to another server with ftp access?

Tags: file-transfer, rsync, scp, ubuntu-server

I have some big folders (each around 1T) on a server which I have sudo access to that. I want to transfer them to another server which I have ftp access (with username and password). What it came in my mind is first to transfer all data to my local machine. Then, upload these through filezilla to the second server.

1. Is this a reasonable action?
2. I have problem with transferring data from server to local machine. Since those folders need sudo access, with usual scp I cannot access them. Through searching, I found some solutions but none of them worked for me. Below is what I have tried:

```
ssh user@server sudo -S tar -C /data/volume1 -cf . | tar -xf-


scp -r user@server:/data/volume1/ /Volumes/C/MyData


rsync -avz --rsync-path="sudo rsync" user@server:/data/volume1/ /Volumes/C/MyData
```

I am not sure where I am making mistake. I would be grateful for your helps.

Comment: What errors do you get when you run those things you've tried?

Comment: @music2myear Mostly permission denied. Also, sometimes only downloading a small part of data. Not sure which one gives which error. I can try them again.

Comment: @music2myear The way to copy files to local and again sending to the other server is pretty time consuming. For each 1 T it take 2-3 days. I am looking for a more efficient way.